# How do you square a Vector in a Python calculation

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy

Lets say you have this code with a Vector and want to square the Vector:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

a, b, c, f, g = sp.symbols('a b c f g')

M = np.array([a, b, c])
```

Now you have a formula in which you need to square this vector like this:

```
B = f * M**2 * g
```

How do you do this, because `np.vectorize(sp.simplify)(M**2)` doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Would something like `np.square(M)` work here?

Comment: Are you trying to do this numerically (i.e. you have a bunch of numbers and you want their squared equivalents) or symbolically (i.e. you want to know the formula to use to obtain each element in the vector)?

Comment: What result would you expect? If I execute your code I get exactly what I would hope to get. And I fail to imagine what other result one would want.

Comment: Which result are you looking for, the one given by `M.dot(M)`, `sp.matrix_multiply_elementwise(M, M)`, or `M*M.T`?

Answer (score 2):

Keep it within Sympy. We can get the squared norm by performing a dot product with itself:

```
a, b, c, f, g = sp.symbols('a b c f g')

M = sp.Matrix([a, b, c])

B = f*(M.dot(M))*g
```

Comment: I think the question requires clarification on what result they are looking for. `M.dot(M)` returns a scalar, but maybe the result they want is `sp.Matrix([a**2, b**2, c**2])` (given by `sp.matrix_multiply_elementwise(M, M)`)? Or maybe the result given by `M*M.T` (a matrix)?

Comment: Thats exactly right, the best way to continue with the caluclation would be using a Vector in sympy, the result, that you get from the M.dot(M) is a 'sympy.vector.vector.VectorAdd' but because of the calculation it produces a 'sympy.core.add.Add' which is not desireable

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import sympy as sp
   ...: 
   ...: a, b, c, f, g = sp.symbols('a b c f g')
   ...: 
   ...: M = np.array([a, b, c])
```

`M` is an object dtype array:

```
In [2]: M
Out[2]: array([a, b, c], dtype=object)
```

Since math operators are defined for `symbols`, we can do 'math' with that array.  `numpy` just iterates through the elements of the object dtype array, and does the calculation as defined that element:

```
In [3]: B = f * M**2 * g    
In [4]: B
Out[4]: array([a**2*f*g, b**2*f*g, c**2*f*g], dtype=object)
```

Your `vectorize` just applies `simplify` to each of the elements of its argument. End up doing nothing:

```
In [5]: fn=np.vectorize(sp.simplify)
In [6]: M**2
Out[6]: array([a**2, b**2, c**2], dtype=object)    
In [7]: fn(M**2)
Out[7]: array([a**2, b**2, c**2], dtype=object)
```

It's unclear what you want to happen.  `sympy` is a symbolic tool, `numpy` a numeric vector one.  They really aren't designed to work together.

Note that for a usual numeric numpy array, square just - squares the elements.

```
In [9]: x= np.array([1,2,3]); x**2
Out[9]: array([1, 4, 9])
```

We can also take inner and outer products:

```
In [10]: x@x
Out[10]: 14
In [11]: x[:,None]*x
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

And again, since basic math operators are defined for symbols, we can do the same with `M`:

```
In [12]: M@M
Out[12]: 
a**2 + b**2 + c**2

In [13]: M[:,None]*M
Out[13]: 
array([[a**2, a*b, a*c],
       [a*b, b**2, b*c],
       [a*c, b*c, c**2]], dtype=object)

In [14]: M[:,None]*M * g * f
Out[14]: 
array([[a**2*f*g, a*b*f*g, a*c*f*g],
       [a*b*f*g, b**2*f*g, b*c*f*g],
       [a*c*f*g, b*c*f*g, c**2*f*g]], dtype=object)
```

Generally a more useful way of using `sympy` with `numpy` is to make a Python function with `lambdify`.

```
In [26]: m=sp.symbols('m')
In [27]: fn=sp.lambdify((f,m,g),f*m**2*g)
In [28]: fn(f,M,g)
Out[28]: array([a**2*f*g, b**2*f*g, c**2*f*g], dtype=object)
```

Which is the same as `B` above.

We could use numbers and numeric arrays in that `fn`:

```
In [31]: fn(10,x,2)
Out[31]: array([ 20,  80, 180])
```

but sympy `subs` in a list comprehension is just as good:

```
In [33]: [(f*m**2*g).subs({f:10,g:2, m:i}) for i in x]
Out[33]: [20, 80, 180]
```

(There's no speed advantage to doing math on object dtype arrays.)